# SWT layout trouble

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

How can i step space as between 3 buttons in right and bottom items; and memory and labelM ???
There must be equal space, moreover memory buttons and digit buttons must be equal height, help me to do this please, becouse my brain couldn't imagine how to do this
this is code

```
package calc;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;

public class View extends ViewPart {
    public Text inputText;
    public Text inputText2;
    public Label label;
    public Label label2;
    public Composite mainComposite;
    public Calculation calcul;

    public View()
    {
        calcul = new Calculation();

    }

    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        Composite mainComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout gltop = new GridLayout(1, false);        
        gltop.numColumns = 1;       
        mainComposite.setLayout(gltop);
        //mainComposite.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
        createTop(mainComposite);
        createBott(mainComposite);      
    }

    private void createTop(Composite parent)
    {
        GridLayout gltop = new GridLayout(1, false);        
        gltop.numColumns = 1;
        GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);     
        Composite topComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);       
        topComposite.setLayout(gltop);
        topComposite.setLayoutData(data);
        //topComposite.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));

        /*inputText = new Text(topComposite, SWT.BORDER);
        inputText.setLayoutData(data);
        inputText.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("", 18, SWT.BOLD));*/
        label = new Label(topComposite,SWT.RIGHT | SWT.BORDER);
        label.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        label.setLayoutData(data);
        label.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("", 18, SWT.BOLD));
        label.setText(calcul.output);
    }

    private void createBott(Composite parent)
    {
        GridLayout glbot = new GridLayout(1, false);        
        glbot.numColumns = 2;
        GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);       
        Composite botComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);       
        botComposite.setLayout(glbot);
        botComposite.setLayoutData(data);
        //botComposite.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW));            

        createLeft(botComposite);       
        createRight(botComposite);      
    }

    private void createLeft(Composite parent)
    {           
        Composite leftComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);  
        GridLayout glleft = new GridLayout(1, false);       
        GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);   
        leftComposite.setLayout(glleft);
        leftComposite.setLayoutData(data);
        //leftComposite.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN)); 
        glleft.marginBottom = 5;
        glleft.marginTop = 7;
        label2 = new Label(leftComposite,SWT.BORDER | SWT.CENTER);
        label2.setLayoutData(data);
        double a = Double.parseDouble(label.getText());
        Button buttonMC = createFuncDigButtons(leftComposite, data, "M+", 'P');
        Button buttonMR = createFuncDigButtons(leftComposite, data, "M-", 'M');
        Button buttonMS = createFuncDigButtons(leftComposite, data, "MR", 'R');
        Button buttonMpl = createFuncDigButtons(leftComposite, data, "MC", 'c');
    }

    private void createRight(Composite parent)
    {
        GridLayout glright = new GridLayout(1, false);      
        GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);       
        Composite rightComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        glright.numColumns = 1;
        glright.horizontalSpacing = 0;
        glright.verticalSpacing = 0;
        rightComposite.setLayout(glright);
        rightComposite.setLayoutData(data);
        //rightComposite.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN));  

        createRightTop(rightComposite);
        createRightBot(rightComposite);
    }

    private void createRightTop(Composite parent)
    {
        Composite rightTopComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout glltop = new GridLayout(1, false);       
        GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);   
        glltop.numColumns = 3;
        glltop.marginBottom = 0;
        rightTopComposite.setLayout(glltop);
        rightTopComposite.setLayoutData(data);
        //rightTopComposite.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_MAGENTA)); 

        Button buttonBack = createFuncDigButtons(rightTopComposite, data, "Backspace", 'B');
        Button buttonC = createFuncDigButtons(rightTopComposite, data, "C", 'C');
        Button buttonCE = createFuncDigButtons(rightTopComposite, data, "CE", 'E');
    }

    private void createRightBot(Composite parent)
    {
        GridLayout glright = new GridLayout(1, false);      
        GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);       
        Composite rightBotComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);      
        glright.numColumns = 5;
        glright.marginTop = 0;
        rightBotComposite.setLayout(glright);
        rightBotComposite.setLayoutData(data);
    //  rightBotComposite.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GRAY));      
        Button button7 = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "7", '7');
        Button button8 = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "8", '8');
        Button button9 = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "9", '9');
        Button buttonDev = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "/", '/');
        Button buttonSQRT = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "sqrt", 't');
        Button button4 = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "4", '4');
        Button button5 = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "5", '5');
        Button button6 = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "6", '6');
        Button buttonMult = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "*", '*');
        Button buttonPer = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "%", '%');
        Button button1 = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "1", '1');
        Button button2 = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "2", '2');
        Button button3 = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "3", '3');
        Button buttonMinus = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "-", '-');
        Button buttonDev1 = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "1/x", 'X');
        Button button0 = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "0", '0');
        Button buttonPM = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "+/-", 'p');
        Button buttonD = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, ".", '.');       
        Button buttonPlus = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "+", '+');        
        Button buttonR = createFuncDigButtons(rightBotComposite, data, "=", '=');
    }

    public Button createFuncDigButtons(Composite parent, GridData gridData, final String digit, final char formethod)
    {
        Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
          button.setLayoutData(gridData);
          button.setText(String.valueOf(digit));
          button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                calcul.getDigit(formethod);
                label.setText(calcul.output);
                if (calcul.memtrue)
                {
                    label2.setText("M");
                }
                else
                {
                    label2.setText("");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
              /* do nothing */
            }
          });
          button.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {         
                    calcul.getDigit(arg0.character);
                    label.setText(calcul.output);
            }});
          button.setFocus();
        return button;
    }

    public void setFocus() {
    }
}
```

and this is image: [image: calculator]

http://s008.radikal.ru/i306/1110/65/0708165834c9.jpg

Comment: I did not get what your problem is... could you explain it better ?

Comment: He wants the two spaces to be equal :)

Comment: You're adding the LayoutData to multiple components, don't do that. I'm looking through the code now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create left and right composites. Instead put all buttons (except Backspace, C, and CE, which should go under a single composite with `horizontalSpan = 3`) directly under `botComposite` and use empty labels for spacing. As @Chris Dennett pointed out, make sure every widget has its own layout data.